Trying to trigger an event once progress bar animation is compete
I'm successfully using the below HTML code to trigger a completion event in our LMS.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Post-Survey: Workplace</title>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('message', e => window.evolve = e.ports[0]);
</script>
</head>

<body class="htmlNoPages">
<center><iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/..." onLoad="evolve?.postMessage('completed')" style="border:none;" height="1000" width="800"/></center>
</body>

</html>

We are trying to create the same trigger using a progress bar that launches on page load and have found the below code sample to help get started, but I can't figure out how to get the bar's end to trigger in the same. Can anyone help?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">

  <div class="w3-light-grey">
    <div id="myBar" class="w3-container w3-green" style="height:24px;width:0%">
    </div>
  </div>

  <p id="myP">Added <span id="demo">0</span> of 10 photos</p>

<body onload="move()">
</div>

<script>

function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      document.getElementById("myP").className = "w3-text-green w3-animate-opacity";
      document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML = "Successfully uploaded 10 photos!";
      window.addEventListener('message', e => window.evolve = e.ports[0]);
      document.addEventListener("load", "evolve?.postMessage('completed')")


    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

I've tried a few iterations of combining these codes, but none have worked.
Ideally, removing any of the text about uploading photos, we would just have a progress bar that starts on page load and when finishing loading, executes the same outcome as the iframe code.

Since the document is already loaded, you can't call evolve?.postMessage('completed') as handler of the load event. Instead just run it directly. (Whatever it does)
window.evolve.postMessage('complete')
Option 2
Let's fake the iframe using javascript.
let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
iframe.onload = function() {
  evolve?.postMessage('completed')
};
iframe.src = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/...';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);


In the original code, onload="evolve?.postMessage('completed')" is used to trigger the  script in the head

That's a good idea. How does that work into the rest of the bottom code?

instead of window.addEventListener('message', e => window.evolve = e.ports[0]); and the line after that

That's what I figured. Unfortunately, it's not working. Is there a way to just trigger evolve?.postMessage('completed') with the iframe or trigger it based on an action other than onload?

Perhaps you can edit into your question some context such as what is evolve and how google forms are related?

Actually, the code was build off of an event being trigger in an iframe by submitting a google form but the google form is not related here.

Evolve is our elearning authoring program. What I'm doing is trying to add a timing bar to a page (this function doesn't exist in the program). When the progress bar comes to an end (ex. 4mins) it fires a completion trigger in Evolve. The only way to do this using HTML is pairing...
<script>     window.addEventListener('message', e => window.evolve = e.ports[0]); </script>
with...
onLoad="evolve?.postMessage('completed')"
